# Empty Range in Multiplication

Tags: summation

Why is the following true?

$$\prod_{i=6}^2 3^i = 1$$

I can't quite wrap my head around it. I understand that

$$\prod_{i=1}^k 3^i = \underbrace{3^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdots 3^{k-1} \cdot 3^k}_{3^{\sum_{j=1}^k}}$$

Is it because that sum is now zero and $3^0 = 1$?

Comment: Seems odd, where did you see this kind of relation? I think the answer should be $\frac{1}{531~441}$.

Comment: It was on exercise sheet. It could have also been $3i$, i don't remember. It's been a while

Comment: Well, that's a world of difference there. But I think surely the answer should not be 1 ...

Comment: Your title suggests that the product actually has no factors. I.e. the product is taken over $\{i\in \mathbb{N}|i\geq 6 \text{ and } i\leq2\}=\{\}$. However this would also be weird notation. It is however reasonable to define the empty product as 1.

Comment: See [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Special_cases) and [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#Logarithms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the author implicitly used a definition such that

$$\prod_{k=a}^b$$ involves all $k$ in $$a\le k\le b,$$ and if that range is empty, the product is $1$ by default (just as a sum is $0$ by default).

Other authors allow bounds reversal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given a ring $R$. By definition, the empty sum is equal to the zero element $0$ of the ring, and the empty product is equal to the unit element $1$ of the ring.